# Compare Json Collection, return change values

Tags: c#, json

I have Json Collection with the different fields. All fields are dynamic. Please take the below example.

```
[{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":1,"A":"2","B":"1","C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":1}
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":2},
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":3},
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":4}]
```

I want to compare Four number json with the first one and identify the changes,
Like in fourth line Memcode is 2 and in first Memcode is 1. So here memcode is change from 2 to 1. 
Like wise for all the fields. this field may be any type like datetime/ string etc. This is just example. JSON may be long with many fields. But all json string is same fields.

All fields are dynamic. I want some method which do above calculation and return field change with the old and new values.

I want to do using C# and `Newtonsoft.Json`. I don't know how to achieve above one. Can you please help me/guide me?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :- 5/10**

Hello, Sorry If I am not clear. Let me Explain Once again.  I want develop some generic method who accept the collection of the JSON. This JSON have a number of different fields.
Suppose Collection have a 5 JSON. ALl 5 JSON have a same number of fields with a different value or may be same values.

Now I want to compare 1st number of JSON with the N number of JSON. Identify which field has been changes. Take that field and it's old value/New value in the Collection. Old value will be N field value and New value will be 1 field value. Continue this way for other JSON. Now 1st Number JSON compare with the N-1. and identify change fields. Continue this way up to all collection finished.

Return value be Fields and Old value, New value.

The field can by string, number of date.

I can do using for loop but I want some generic method which is time efficient and align with the new C# feature.

Hope I am clear this time.
Thank you so much..

Comment: If you use dynamic deserializer then it will identify the types then you can use default comparer for that type

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the result? What is the expected result, what does _field change_ mean?

Comment: Hello, Sorry If I am not clear. Let me Explain Once again.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic and convert your Json object as bellow

```
 dynamic data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(your Json Object);
```

Then use normal foreach loop on data  to compare

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know this thing but I want something generalize solution. which can accept any JSON with the number of different fields in collection.      Suppose there is 5 JSON string in Collection. I want to compare First with the Five one and Identify which field change. After that second JSON compare with the Five one and Identify more changes and so on....

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each `JSON` object to `List<string>` where string represents one or more `JSON` attributes. Then compare those lists using `Except` method. Each `JSON` object is serialized to `string` which is then split by `,`. By splitting, `JSON` attributes are extracted. `objArray` is the array containing `JSON` objects.

```
        List<List<string>> jsonAttList = new List<List<string>>();

        int objArrayLength = objArray.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < objArrayLength; i++)
        {
            string objString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objArray[i]);
            jsonAttList.Add(objString.Split(',').ToList());
        }
```

Or shorter

```
List<List<string>> jsonAttList = new List<List<string>>();
objArray.ForEach(item => jsonAttList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item).Split(',').ToList()));
```

Here are four examples you provided with one additional attribute.

```
[{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":1,"A":"2","B":"1","myObj":{"X":1,"Y":2},"C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":1},
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":2}
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","myObj":{"X":1,"Y":3},"C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":3},
{"KB":"1","Id":"01","MemCode":2,"A":"2","B":"1","myObj":{"X":1,"Y":2,"Z":3},"C":"2010-01-01T00:00:00","D":4}]
```

Difference between two `JSON` objects is list of strings.

Difference between first and second `JSON` object is list containing: `"MemCode":1`, `"myObj":{"X":1`, `"Y":2}` and `"D":1}`.

```
        var difference01 = jsonAttList[0].Except(jsonAttList[1]).ToList();
```

Difference between first and third `JSON` object is list containing: `"MemCode":1`, `"Y":2}` and `"D":1}`.

```
        var difference02 = jsonAttList[0].Except(jsonAttList[2]).ToList();
```

Difference between first and fourth `JSON` object is list containing: `"MemCode":1`, `"Y":2}` and `"D":1}`.

```
        var difference03 = jsonAttList[0].Except(jsonAttList[3]).ToList();
```

Difference between fourth and first `JSON` object is list containing: `"MemCode":2`, `"Y":2`, `"Z":3}` and `"D":4}`.

```
        var difference30 = jsonAttList[3].Except(jsonAttList[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marko. Is it possible generic solution for this ? I got your point. I have also similar solution but I don't want any for loop. I want some generic solution. Do you have any idea ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @user13509456, sorry for the late reply. I am glad I could help. I've edited the answer and added shorter way to split JSON.